# LESS mixins with multiple parameters raises syntax error

Tags: css, less, gruntjs

I wrote this followed the documentation of the LESS website, the mixins part, which I thought would work but raises a syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: properties must be inside selector blocks, they cannot be in the
root. in less/style.less on line 3, column 3:  
2 .bg (@x; @y) {  
3   background-position: unit(@x, px) unit(@y, px);  
4 }
```

Here is the Less:

```
.bg (@x; @y) {
  background-position: unit(@x, px) unit(@y, px);
}
.mydiv (@x:0; @y:-52; @width:300px; @height: 155px) {
  .bg(@x, @y);
  width: @width;
  height: @height;
  opacity: 1;
}

.mydiv()
```

also if I just use only multiple parameters it cause the same error:

```
SyntaxError: properties must be inside selector blocks, they cannot be in the  
root. in less/style.less on line 14, column 3:  
13 .mydiv(@width:300px; @height: 155px) {  
14   background-position: 0px -52px;  
15   width: @width;
```

Less:

```
.mydiv (@width:300px; @height: 155px) {
  background-position: 0px -52px;
  width: @width;
  height: @height;
  opacity: 1;
}

.mydiv()
```

I don't know what's wrong with it...please help...
quote: i'm using less with grunt-contrib-less, and less 1.4.2, in windows 8.1 x64.

Answer (score 10):

You're calling `.mydiv()` outside the scope of CSS block, that would (hypothetically) would output incorrect CSS. something like:

```
/* some arbitrary css: */
body { font-family: Arial; }
a { text-decoration: underline; }

 /* your mixin (invalid): */
background-position: 0px -52px;
width: @width;
height: @height;
opacity: 1;
```

You have to wrap the mixin call within a CSS block, something like:

```
.bg (@x; @y) {
  background-position: unit(@x, px) unit(@y, px);
}
.mydiv (@x:0; @y:-52; @width:300px; @height: 155px) {
  .bg(@x, @y);
  width: @width;
  height: @height;
  opacity: 1;
}

.myClassThatUsesMyDiv
{
   .mydiv()

   /* can be with some other directives: */
   background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But is there any better way to do it? perhaps not with mixins, what I want is to define the all the functions in one place and call it in another place with different parameters.

Comment: `what I want is to define the all the functions in one place and call it in another place with different parameters` is exactly what you have now. the only problem is **where** you're calling it. CSS simply doesn't let you emit directives that are not within the scope of a block.

Answer (score 4):

Using mixin containing attributes **outside** any other elements will result in incorrect CSS, and the error you've come across is because LESS compiler wants to prevent that.

---

**Q: So how do I use my mixin?**

A: Make sure you understand what is a mixin definition, and what is a mixin call.

I'll use simplified examples to clearly explain this.

This is mixin **definition**:

```
.sample-mixin (@color; @width: 100px) {  
  color: @color;
  display: block;
  width: @width;  
}
```

To **use** such a mixin, you just call it like a function:

```
.sample-mixin(#eeffee);    // this line is actual mixin call
```

Mixin call is evaluated to **whole mixin content** (with variables evaluated):

```
color: #eeffee;
display: block;
width: 100px;
```

---

**Q: When calling mixins outside other block is incorrect?**

A: If your mixins contains **at least one attribute**:

```
.sample-mixin (@color) {
  color: @color; 
}
```

Then calling it outside block:

```
 .sample-mixin(#eeffee);
```

Results in **incorrect** CSS:

```
color: #eeffee;
```

But calling it inside block:

```
 p {
   .sample-mixin(#eeffee);
 }
```

Is allright, as it results in correct CSS:

```
p {
  color: #eeffee;
}
```

---

**Q: When calling mixins outside other block is correct?**

A: Only if your mixins contains **nothing but blocks**:

```
.sample-mixin (@color) {
  body { 
   color: @color; 
  }    
}
```

Then calling it outside block:

```
 .sample-mixin(#eeffee);
```

Results in correct CSS:

```
body {
  color: #eeffee;
}
```

Sidenote: having blocks inside mixins is **not a good practice**, as it can effectively confuse readers and results in higher coupling inside your CSS.